# NetworkOnMainThreadException in Android Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, multithreading, networkonmainthread

I'm creating an android application in which i'm using Facebook connectivity.I used this tutorial for reference.But when i tried to parse json,it gave me NetworkOnMainThreadException.I dont exactly know how to use thread and AsynTask properly.Somebody please help me out with fixing this...

Here is my class...

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

    Button btn;
    Facebook fb;
    ImageView loginButton,profilePicture;
    TextView username;
    Bitmap bmp;
    SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fb = new Facebook("xxxxxx");
        sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = sp.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if(access_token !=null)
        {
            fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires !=0)
        {
            fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        loginButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        profilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_profpic);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

     public void onClick(View view) 
     {

         if(fb.isSessionValid())
            {
                // logout
                try {
                    fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                     new GetProfile().execute("");

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //login
                fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,new String[] {"email"},new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "MSG: "+e.getMessage()+ " CODE: "+e.getErrorCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Editor editor = sp.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                        //new GetProfile().execute("");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }

            }

     private class GetProfile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
     {

         @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
            {
             if(fb.isSessionValid())
            {
                loginButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.fb_logout);
                profilePicture.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

                JSONObject obj = null;
                URL img_url = null;


                try {
                    String jsonUSer = fb.request("me");
                    obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUSer);

                    String id = obj.optString("id");
                    String name = obj.optString("name");

                    img_url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=small");
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_url.openConnection().getInputStream());

                } 
                catch (FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
                return "Executed";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String name) 
            {
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);

                username.setText("Welcome, "+name);

                profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
                // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
        }
```

Comment: "I dont exactly know how to use thread and AsynTask properly" -- what have you tried, and what specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please see the updated Question.I dont really understand what is giving me error.Please help...